# Random Graphs: Examples of their Uses

Tags: statistics, graph-theory, random-graphs

Just writing a paper at the moment on random / random geometric graphs.

If any of you could perhaps give examples, as broad and interesting as possible, of where these have been used across science? I have plenty of examples, but thought this might be a good place to get some breadth of use.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the Barabási-Albert model appears in context of social networks, neural networks and power grids. It is good because it reflects some properties that theses networks have, like the degree distribution is a power law. You can see this on the paper of Barabási and Albert:

[Emergence of Scaling in random Networks](http://arxiv.org/abs/condmat/9910332)

If you want something more recent, the preferential attachment models with fitness seems to appears in recommendation algorithms. Some comments about it you can find here:

[First to Market is not Everything: an Analysis of Preferential Attachment with Fitness](http://arxiv.org/abs/0710.4982)

by Borgs, Chayes, Daskalakis and Roch.

This use of random graphs is pretty interesting once the actual advertisement model is based on such algorithms. Google, Netflix, Facebook, Yahoo... All theses big companies are interested in such algorithms.

Hope this can help!

Comment: No problem. If you are interested in applications on the internet you can find them in the book "A Course on the Web Graph" there you can find a better explanation about random graphs and PageRank algorithms, for example.